# How to save value other than Dropdownlistfor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a case where I have to enable users to fill in a value in a text box if users select "Other" value in `@HTML.Dropdownlistfor`. I still not be able to do it, and could not find a solution for ASP.NET MVC on the internet.

Below is my sample code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Material of Construction</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CorrGroup.cGroup_MatConst, (SelectList)ViewBag.MaterialConstruction)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Other Materials @Html.TextBox("OtherMaterials", "", new { @class = "mandatoryTextArea", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have disabled the textbox - how can a user enter a value?

Comment: I disabled it because user does not yet select "Other" value in dropdownlistfor. If user select the value only then the Textbox will be enabled. My question is how I can save value other than listed in Dropdownlistfor listed value.

Comment: You model needs a property `string OtherMaterials`

Comment: oh....I think I got your Idea....if let's say user choose "Others", and fill in otherMaterial field, the value will be stored as OtherMaterials, and "Others" value will be stored as cGroup_MatConst in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add this selection to your SelectList in the controller.